# Creating a new JFrame on label click

Tags: java, object-oriented, swing

So I've been looking for examples on the internet for a while now and this seems the most common way everyone is suggesting, but now I ask is there a better way to make a new jframe pop up on click than this.

The code :

```
JLabel prevention = new JLabel("<html><U><font color='red'>Prevencija</font><U></html>");
    prevention.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 100));
    prevention.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JFrame jf = new JFrame("Prevencija");
            jf.setContentPane(new PreventionPanel());
            jf.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
    bottom.add(prevention);
```

Comment: do you create more than one such clickable label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the code is quite okay, here are a few remarks.

- Maybe extract the body of the `mouseClicked()` method into a separate method, in case you have more code that would perform the same action, like when listening to keystrokes as well.
- Consider using a `JButton` instead of a `JLabel` and use an `ActionListener` or even an `Action` instead of a `MouseListener`. Using a `MouseListener` for reacting on `mouseClicked` on the entire area of a `JLabel` seems like replicating something on a physical level for which Swing already provides something on a logical level.
- I'd use `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` instead of `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, as that's the original definition.
- I'd use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and dispose all frames. Applications which use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` become more difficult to test. When `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` doesn't work it usually means that you have a bad application design or bugs regarding threading.
- Depending on what you want to achieve, you might be more interested in using `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` instead of `JFrame` for this use case. Maybe `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`. I can only recommend to look into those, not tell whether those are better for your use case, as your code and description don't give enough information for more.